# Removing Controller name from URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes

Currently in my CI project I have a single controller that handles all things account. Such-as register, login, activation, etc.

My routes work as such...

`domain.com/account/login/` or `domain.com/account/register/`

How can I remove `account` from the route while also being about to remove the controller from other pages.

I basically want the controller to always be removed. One of my reasons for this is SEO, search engine rank the importunateness of a page based on how deep it is in a website.

The only way I have seem to achieve this is to do some thing like `route['activate'] = 'account/activate';` for every single page, which would be a huge hassle.

Comment: do you foresee any methods having identical method names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you DO have to explicitly set the routes.

How is it going to know which controller a given function is in????

You have to tell it.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but I was hoping for some magic :)

Comment: if you want magic, use rails, codeigniter expects YOU to be the magician.

Answer (score 4):

```
$route['^(?!other|controllers).*'] = “account/$0″;
```

Comment: This worked for me. Because of how URL's are being rewritten on my install, I needed to use `$route['^(?!/other|/controllers).*'] = "controller/$0";`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$route['(:any)'] = "account/$1";
```

Comment: The problem with this is, that I have more than one controller.

Comment: I answered this since you mentioned "I have a single controller that handles all things account".. if you have different controllers you have to explicitly set routes for each controllers.

Comment: Ah I see sorry, but I also later mentioned that I would like to do it to all my controllers.

Answer (score 1):

use mod_rewrite (if the controller is always the same name)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I can think of one way to do this, but it is probably gonna be more of a pain than just writing out routes for each function.

You need to extend the `Router.php` with `application/core/MY_Router.php` and overide the `_validate_request()` method. Which basically decides if this this is a valid route or not.

it does a check to see if the controller class exists then fails if it doesn't exist.
You need to replace this with some code which assumes no controller segment, then scans thru each of your controllers and checks if it contains the method called (it will be segment 1, since theres no controller).

Now the tricky part, at this point in the CI lifecycle your controller obviously isnt loaded, so you cant examine it using [method_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) yet.

You need to load your controllers one at a time, and then for each one run

```
method_exists($loaded_class, $method_name)
```

and if its true, then set then go ahead and call:

```
$this->set_class('the_name_of_the_scanned_class_which_had_the_method');
```

Then CI can keep going on as normal and it will load your methods without the user ever know what controller it loaded from.

.. probably not worth the hassle imho. A much easier solution would be to just have one controller and one route to that controller.